# Negative surgeries on negative knots

Tags: knot-theory, 3-manifolds, surgery-theory

This question is two-fold.

The first question is rather specific: what are some small examples of negative surgeries on negative knots that give rise to the same 3-manifold? I know one class of examples coming from Borromean rings. By performing $-1/m$ and $-1/n$ surgery on two components of the Borromean rings, we get the double twist knot $K_{m,n}$ which is negative. Now, $-1/l$ surgery on $K_{m,n}$ is just $-1/l$, $-1/m$ and $-1/n$ surgery on the Borromean rings, and by the symmetry of the Borromean rings, it is the same as $-1/m$ surgery on $K_{l,n}$ and $-1/n$ surgery on $K_{l,m}$. I would like to know some other simple examples (preferably with knots with small number of crossings).

The second question is a bit vague: what is known about the class of 3-manifolds obtained as negative surgeries on negative knots? I am curious to know if there are some theorems saying this class of 3-manifolds are "nice" in some way. Any kind of input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is negative knots? Also can you please elaborate your example, it is not clear to me.

Comment: @Anubhav A negative knot is a knot that has a knot diagram with only negative crossings.

Comment: To your convention, the right-handed trefoil is negative knot, right?

Comment: @Oguz Right-handed trefoil is positive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(-7)$-surgery on the left-handed trefoil yields the lens space $L(7,2)$ which is defined to be the $(-7/2)$-surgery along the unknot.

Similarly one can get more examples along negative torus knots producing lens spaces. Moser classified all surgeries along torus knots in [L. Moser, Elementary surgery along a torus knot, Pacific J. Math. 38 (1971), 737–745.].

Answer (score 3):

In general, to find explicit examples for the first part of your question is a hard problem, sometimes impossible. Actually, it is related to the notion of *cosmetic surgeries*, see Ni and Wu's [paper](http://www.its.caltech.edu/%7Eyini/Published/Cosmetic.pdf), and further articles.

You may predict conjectures or obtain obstructions due to Thurston's theorem: all but finitely many surgeries on a hyperbolic knot result in hyperbolic manifolds.

On the other hand, as Kegel said, L. Moser completely classified surgeries along torus knots as follows:

**Theorem:** Let $K$ be an $(r,s)$ torus knot in $S^3$ and let $Y$ be the $3$-manifold obtained by performing a $(p,q)$-surgery along $K$. Set $\sigma =rsp−q$.

**(a).** If $|\sigma|>1$, then $Y$ is the Seifert manifold $\Sigma(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3)$ over $S^2$ with three exceptional fibers of multiplicities $\alpha_1=s, \alpha_2=r$ and $\alpha_3=|\sigma|$.

**(b).** If $\sigma =±1$, then $Y$ is the lens space $L(|q|,ps^2)$.

**(c).** If $\sigma =0$, then $Y$ is the connected sum of lens spaces $L(r,s) \#L(s,r)$.

**EDIT:** Considering mirror symmetry of knots and following the common convention on surgeries, we have for $n \geq 1$,

1. $\Sigma(r,s,rsn-1)$ is obtained by $(-1,n)$-surgery along the left-handed $(r,s)$ torus knot.
2. $\Sigma(r,s,rsn+1)$ is obtained by $(-1,n)$-surgery along the right-handed $(r,s)$ torus knot.

Note that these are only integral homology spheres obtained by surgery on a torus knot in $S^3$.

Comment: Moser's notation is somehow non-standard. When she says $(p,q)$-surgery, she means gluing the meridian $\mu$ to $q\mu+p\lambda$, I think. Most people define this as the $(q,p)$-surgery. I am also not sure if the orientation of the lens spaces is really the one induced via the group action on $S^3$ or if she is working with the opposite one.

Comment: @MarcKegel thanks for your attention. You are right. To the common convention, what L. Moser did is $(q,p)$-surgery on the torus knot in $S^3$. I will edit the post thinking about the orientations.